# Processing: How do I set a client to read multiple messages sent at once from a server as separate?

Tags: networking, network-programming, processing

I am working on setting up a basic network system in Processing:

```
import processing.net.*;
Server myServer;
Client myClient;
```

However, I'm having trouble with my server and client side communication set up. My client is interpreting all incoming messages as Strings, and the issue is that whenever multiple messages are sent from the server in the same frame, they become added into a single string, which my program cannot interpret. After testing, I found that sending multiple messages from a single client to the server are given the same treatment.

My client reader looks like this:

```
while (myClient.available() > 0) {
  String dataIn = myClient.readString();
```

As of now, I don't know if the problem is in the reader (combining the strings), or in the fact that I'm using write() multiple times in a single frame (and the data is being sent as a single string).

I am wondering if the messages can somehow be sent/read separately or, if not, there is some method to test if a message has already been sent (that works for both the client and server side) so that I can set up a queue to keep track of messages to be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to forgo the idea of checking if a message had already been sent as I did not see any functions that would be able to help do that. Instead, I went ahead and created an arrayList of strings for the server called serverQ to act as a queue for messages to be sent:

```
ArrayList <String> serverQ = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I also added a function writeSQ(String) that would place any input string into the queue:

```
void writeSQ(String s) {
  serverQ.add(s);
}
```

I then proceeded to replace every usage of myServer.write(String) with writeSQ(String s). At the end of my ServerUpdate function, I added a section that would empty the queue, sending the next string to all clients, one frame at a time:

```
  //  send data
  if (serverQ.size() > 0) {
      myServer.write(serverQ.get(0));
      serverQ.remove(0);
    }
  }
```

However, for some reason, messages still got compounded, so I speculated that it may be due to the closeness (frequency) of the sent messages (each frame); so I set a boolean serverSent to alternate the messages sent to every other frame. The new code looks like this:

```
  //  send data
  if (serverQ.size() > 0) {
    if (!serverSent) {
      myServer.write(serverQ.get(0));
      serverQ.remove(0);
      serverSent = true;
    } else
      serverSent = false;
  }
```

This worked perfectly and the messages were interpreted individually by clients. I added that exact same support code to the clients (changing everything from server to client when needed) and after a good amount of testing, can confirm that this new support works properly both ways.